# How can i deal with this problem while install mongodb on centos 7?

Tags: mongodb, installation

After install mongodb on CentOS, I'm typingthe command `systemctl status mongod`, but the following problem appears (also see picture):

> systemctl status mongod ● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
>   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled;
>   vendor preset: disabled) Active: failed (Result: exit-code) 02-28
>   20:17:01 CST; Process: 3558 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS
>   (code=exited, status=2) Process: 3556 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755
>   /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) Process: 3554
>   ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
>   (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) Process: 3547
>   ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited,
>   status=0/SUCCESS)

Thank you so much for reading my problem. If you can help me solve the problem, I will appreciate it very much.
[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DiTX.png)

Comment: systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) 02-28 20:17:01 CST;
  Process: 3558 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 3556 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3554 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3547 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Answer (score 1):

This happends often when you started the service as a different user.
Follow this:
- try first stoping the service.

> sudo systemctl stop mongod

- then remove this file:

> sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

- restart mongodb service

  > sudo systemctl start mongod

---

if that doesnt do it, i would suggest to remove mongodb and follow this guide: (it worked for me perfectly on CentOS 7)

try installing mongodb like this:

- Create a /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.2.repo file so that you can install MongoDB directly using yum:

> ```
> sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org.repo
> ```

- Paste this inside the mongodb-org.repo

> ```
>  [mongodb-org-4.2]
>      name=MongoDB Repository
>      baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/4.2/x86_64/
>      gpgcheck=1
>      enabled=1
>      gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc
> ```

- verify that the MongoDB repository exists

> ```
> yum repolist
> ```

- Installing mongodb

> ```
> sudo yum install mongodb-org
> ```

- Start the mongodb service:

> ```
> sudo systemctl start mongod
> ```

- The reload command requests that the mongod process reads the configuration file, /etc/mongod.conf, and applies any changes without requiring a restart

> ```
> sudo systemctl reload mongod
> ```

- try access the database server with the MongoDB Shell:

> mongo

---

this helped me allot on centos7, 
let me know if you need anything else.
cheers, 
Radi

Comment: Problem is maybe you started the service as a different user. try stoping the service, deleting "mongodb-27017.sock" with "sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"
then start the service again